# Synchronizing on-premises DB with Cloud (Azure )

Tags: azure, synchronization, database-replication, mainframe

I have a Mainframe DB2 within my corporate network. I am asked to come up with an approach to create a miniature of this DB in Azure. What would be the best way to implement this? What is the best practice to establish a reliable and secure synchronization between these two DBs?

Comment: Hey Thomas - sounds fairly important to your organization. However: There is no "best" way. Unfortunately this question is way too broad and opinion-based for StackOverflow. Plus you're asking multiple questions (your second question is around synchronization). And finally... it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

There are commercial products that do this sort of thing...google "DB2 SQL Server Synchronization". If you want a simple way to start, the ETL (Extract, Transform, Load) vendors - Informatica, Tibco, SyncSort, etc - all have variations on this capability.

It is much more challenging than it sounds because the two databases have such different feature sets. While you might get a simple set of tables to work, soon as you introduce triggers, stored procedures, EBCDIC vs. ASCII issues and so forth, you'll be wanting all the help you can get.

Comment: This one we're trying to close (it has amassed three votes out of five so far). It is off-topic for Stack Overflow, so it's best not to answer these. With five votes they first go on hold, after seven days without remedial action they become closed, and then with no updated answers can be eligible for automatic deletion.

Comment: Ah - didn't mean to encourage bad behavior... :)